# Lag only in Safari 11 scroll in webpage

Tags: web, scroll, safari, lag, nicescroll

In this page of [website](http://cssspice.ir/en/audio).

I have scroll lag only in Safari 11 (no problem with Firefox and Chrome). in this project we use HTML, CSS, Jquery and Nicescroll.

We remove all nicescroll action but lag still stay.